# How to use FindWindow() from a service application?

Tags: delphi, winapi

I need to communicate a service application with vcl application.
My old application was a console and console communicates without problems with the vcl app.
Now I migrate the console app to a srv app.
The old communication used FindWindow and SendMessage.

I know I can do the communication btw them using socket or named pipe, BUT, I don't want to change the structure now 'cause it will delay the migration.

Some one knows how I can "fix" it ?

tks

Answer (score 8, accepted):

FindWindow won't work from a service in Vista or Win7, because services run in a different desktop than user applications; neither will SendMessage, because you can't get the window handle. This means that you have to use a different means of communication between them if you'll be supporting these versions of the OS.

Comment: +1 In fact, you can get the window handle, you just can do anything with it from a different session!! But that's just pedantry!

Comment: Agreed. That is just pedantry. <G>

Comment: Alright, I read this on internet but I agree with you, I'll need to change the behavior.

Answer (score 1):

Would ControlService work in place of SendMessage? I think you should be able to pass it your existing structure.

http://www.delphigroups.info/3/10/156645.html

Comment: `ControlService()` does not allow you to send parameters to the service, so it is not a suitable replacement if you need to pass data around.

Answer (score 1):

You can't fix it. Services now run in a different session and without access to the user's desktop. The solution is a named pipe.